# Django query to Sum the lengths of ArrayFields

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-aggregation, django-annotate

I have this model:

```
class Interaction(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    codes = ArrayField(models.CharField(choices=CODE_CHOICES))
```

and I'm trying to figure out how to do the equivalent of this SQL query in Django:

```
select user_id, sum(cardinality(codes)) from interaction group by user_id;
```

- I tried `extra(select={codes_len':'cardinality(codes)'})`, but you
  cannot `annotate` or `aggregate` over an `extra` field.
- I tried `annotate(Sum("cardinality('codes')"))`, but
  `cardinality('codes')` isn't a field on the model.
- I investigated writing a custom aggregate field that combined `Sum`
  and `cardinality`, but that looked... brittle.
- I discovered in the docs that `__len` does work properly on an
  `ArrayField`, but not in the context of
  `annotate(Sum('codes__len'))`.
- I ruled out raw SQL because there are a lot of `WHERE` statements (omitted here) which make this query difficult to reconstruct by hand.

At this point I think I have no other choice but to add a field to the model that is the length of the `codes` field and mess with `save()` to keep it in sync.

Is there really no other way?  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the custom aggregate function is the way to go!

With the following:

```
from django.db.models import Aggregate

class SumCardinality(Aggregate):
    template = 'SUM(CARDINALITY(%(expressions)s))'
```

The query is as simple as:

```
Interaction.objects().filter(xxx).\
    values('user_id').annotate(codes_len=SumCardinality('codes'))
```